# Setting properties in resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, embedded-resource

My site needs to be french and english and I am using resource files to accomplish this. My boss now wants to see sample text inside the text boxes. We are using telerik controls to do this and I am trying to set the sample text to either english or french.

I may have to make a custom control for this so I can have an extra label that is the sample text.

My question is: Can you set other properties besides the text property in the resource files.

ie: Label1Resource.EmptyMessage.Text

with resource set to: Empty message

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For local resources ASP.NET matches the attributes in the element:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblErrorMsg" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="lblErrorMsg" Text="Label">  
</asp:Label>
```

So in the resource file you would define the localized text for "Text" as:

> name: *lblErrorMsg.Text* and value: *Label*

If you have an attribute on the telrik control named *EmptyText* you would address that property in the resource file as such:

> name: *lblErrorMsg.EmptyText* value: *Your text*

Comment: I know how to do the firstpart like you said and it works fine but I can't set the property. Try setting the label to visible="false" in resource file. Is ther e a way to do this?

Comment: yes. Every property you can set as an attribute on the tag (in html) you can set in the resouce file. lblErrorMsg.Visible with value "false" is alright to have in the resource file.

Comment: You also have the possibility to set the value used _explicitly_ by using this notation: <asp:Label ID="Label2" Runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, Msg1 %>"> for a file "LocalizedText.resx" placed in "App_GlobalResources" and a resource key (name) of "Msg1". See [Explicit Localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I cant do lbl.visible and set it to false for some reason but i want it like this: Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, Msg1 %>" is there a way to do this in local resources? not global?

Comment: Couldn't you write <asp:Label ID="Label2" Runat="server" visible="<%=GetLocalResourceObject("yourkey").ToString()" %>">

Comment: But why would you like to localize the property "visible"?

Comment: Just tried this: <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Welcome to ASP.NET!" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1" Visible="true" /> with this in resource file Default.aspx.resx in App_LocalResources: Label1Resource1.Visible=false works like a charm. The label is not displayed.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked. You need emt:resourcekey="something" and in resx file you need something.propertyYouWantToSet with a value: theValueYouWantToSetItTo